# What is the car name for this.....?

Tags: vehicle-identification

I’ve been trying to figure out if this is a kit car or a known car maker for days

It almost looks similar to the Ferrari California. [image]

Comment: Nose badge looks like Maserati's but I'm used to them be more oblong. Yours looks more  circular.  Plus, Maseratis generally (always?) have a trident in the grille.

Comment: @mike65535 - Agree with the Maserati badge assessment, as that's what it looks like. The big problem with that, though, is Maserati's don't come with a front split bumper. *Every* example I see of them, no matter what model, shows a single nostril, and not split in the center. I'm also only seeing them with tridents center in the grille. I'll continue looking. It would be great to know if this is an image from the internet or something outside the OP's window, and what part of the world it's from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Fisker Karma hybrid car.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisker_Karma

Comment: Nailed it ... good job!